# Swift AVAudioPlayer not playing sound on some devices

Tags: swift, audio

I created a class for playing an audio but it doesn't work for all iPhones and I don't understand why not.

this is my class:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class Audio: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?   
    static var play = Audio()

    func withData(data: Data?) {
        if data != nil {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data!)
                audioPlayer?.delegate = self
                audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer?.play()
            
            } catch { print(error) }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I try to play a sound I write:

```
Audio.play.withData(data: someData)
```

It works but on some devices like iPhone X for example it doesn't. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: This is a heavily disguised Singleton. I would recommend a cleaner object architecture.

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Yes, I've done that [many times](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/ddd2b9f22660b61a2878cf60812a814ecc8b85b1/bk2ch14p643ducking/ch27p912ducking/Player.swift). But I don't know what you need an example of; I'm just suggesting that `static var play = Audio()` is a poor idea. I don't know whether it has anything to do with the claim that it "doesn't work" (whatever _that_ means), but I do think that it's better to structure code in a clear and reliable way.